# Why tomcat not serving for request after moving some files into it on running state?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have five application which are running on tomcat-8.5.4. I moved any of the files(like .wav,.txt,.jsp and etc) under any one of the application. The tomcat getting stuck after few mins or hour.I don't know exact time when this issue will happen. I did not get any solution for this. so please help me to resolve the issue.

**Note** : The below issue occurred frequently once it started.

**catlina error log line :**

```
15-Apr-2020 07:44:18.784 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

15-Apr-2020 07:44:18.784 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest Error finishing response
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(Http11OutputBuffer.java:533)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.endRequest(Http11OutputBuffer.java:318)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest(Http11Processor.java:1787)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1149)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Socket



ProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: A lot of information is missing here - what exactly are you trying to do? what exactly are you trying to move where? Are you trying to replace deployed files? Does your serivce work as expected when you don't move files around?

Please extend on the information provided.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. yes you are right, I gave minimum info only. but the problem is I did not get more info from that problem. Yes we tried  to replace and add new files after deployment. can I do this kind of operation after completed the deployment ? I don"t know much more about it. please direct me if I am doing wrong way.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to replace files from an exploded `.war`-file while the server is running.
I am unsure if tomcat does support this directly, but from my experience this often causes problems.
It would be better to rebuild and replace the `.war`-file, use a Hot-Deployment feature from your IDE or a Plugin like JRebel.

Comment: Ok..Thank you.. @Stefan Helmerichs